# Stripping out HTML characters to display image

Tags: php, joomla, json, joomla3.2

I am trying to display the intro image from Joomla 3.2, this is saved into the database in the 'images' column within the table. However, the intro image and the full text image is saved into the same column, so when I'm trying to echo that column I'm just getting the values.

I'm seeing the values by this:

```
<?php echo $item->images; ?>
```

This is outputting the following:

> {"image_intro":"images/stories/imagetest.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}

Ideally though, I want to be able to strip the html out and only display the value for the "image_intro" which I can then use for the img src. The above appears to be in JSON format but I can't figure out how to just echo the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$decodedJsonString = json_decode('{"image_intro":"images/stories/Catcchampcocktails (2).jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}');

echo $decodedJsonString->image_intro;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried the following and it worked: `<?php $images = json_decode($item->images);?>` and then `<?php $jsonString = json_decode($item->images); ?>` `<img src="<?php echo $jsonString->image_intro;?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>"  />` Which worked perfectly!

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to refer to this documentation to see all of the fields you can access: [tables/content](http://docs.joomla.org/Tables/content).

You are correct in saying that Joomla stores the image data in a JSON string in the database